# Ничего тревожного в том, чтобы пометить сообщение, под вопросом/ответом, как ненужное — нет

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, локализация, тревоги

Не совсем разумно называть действие по запросу на удаление устаревшего сообщения, как тревога: это же не оскорбление, не злоупотребление и проверяется, могу предположить, не в первую очередь. Предлагаю переименовать действие "тревога" в что-то наподобие "пометить сообщение".

Answer (score 7):

В принципе, `flag` действительно переводится как `пометить`, но на мой взгляд такой перевод не отражает негативную составляющую. Пометить можно что-то интересное, можно пометить для того, чтобы прочитать потом. А кнопка явно должна показывать, что она предназначена для уведомления о негативном действии (требуется удалить, требуется исправить и т. д.). Поэтому вариант `тревога` мне нравится больше.

Comment: Ну, "тревога" слишком сурово звучит. Надо подумать...